# How Do I Extract the ME in forecast::accuracy() Function

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I can use the `accuracy` function to get a set of accuracy measure for a model as follows:

```
set.seed(289805)
x <- arima.sim(n=10, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
mod <- auto.arima(x, ic="aicc")
fit <- fitted(mod) # fit the model with the series
ACCURACY <- forecast::accuracy(fit, x)      # RETURNS ACCURACY
ACCURACY

# RESULT
#                ME     RMSE       MAE      MPE    MAPE      ACF1 Theil's U
#Test set 0.4763398 1.289879 0.8928214 4.748337 71.5307 0.2324054  1.009128
```

How do I extract only the `ME` in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a matrix so you need to use matrix subsetting.

```
ACCURACY[,"ME"]
[1] 0.4763398
```